# Running a python installer/builder within a python script in different folders

Tags: python

I have a python code that links C code into Python that I want to run. This code is inside the folder `mymodule/foo` which contains two files: a `setup.py` file and a `foo.c` file. What you usually had to do is to enter the `mymodule/foo` folder, and do

```
python setup.py build
```

This creates a .so file which you can then import in python. I have to do this for several sub-folders in the `mymodule` folder, so I wanted to do this automatically via an `os.system()` call. However, when I'm on the `mymodule` folder and do this:

```
os.system('python foo/setup.py build')
```

I get

```
gcc: error: foo.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

Apparently the `setup.py` file is trying to find the `foo.c` code in `mymodule` folder and not on the `mymodule/foo` folder. So far, my solution has been to copy the `foo.c` file into the `mymodule` folder, run that line of code, and then remove the copy of the file from `mymodule` folder. I find this solution, however, messy.

Do you have any ideas on how to do this elegantly?

Comment: Have you given the right path inside setup.py? Instead of copying foo.c, you can chdir in the python code and execute setup.py.

Comment: setup.py is actually the problem, because it searches for the file foo.c inside the folder it resides. And I totally forgot about the chdir command! Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see if it works.

Comment: Meh. Doing os.system('cd foo') and then os.system('python setup.py build') didn't work. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You want `os.chdir`.  `os.system('cd foo')` only changes the directory in the subshell spawned.

Comment: amit/zigg, please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix setup.py or chdir to the required directory using [os.chdir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).